# Tooltip with title and featured image Wordpress function

Tags: wordpress

I want to code a function to get a popup or tooltip which shows the featured image and the title of an internal link when you hover a link on a post or page.

Does anybody know if this is possible and knows how? I know you have to use some filter hook of Wordpress and to use `get_post_field('post_title')` and `$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`.

I think it can only be done with a function that has to be put in the `functions.php`.

Comment: I think you can do it via ajax. Just a primary thought, on hover of the link, you can capture the link slug and pass to the back-end function (in functions.pphp) as a parameter. That function, using the passed argument will query the required data of the link and return to js. Using the returned data JS will format it to be usable as a tool-tip.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your message. I have little knowledge of ajax and would prefer to do it in with WordPress hooks and filters.

Comment: I doubt if this can be achieved via just hooks and/or filters. At least I don't know any of such hooks/filter which would provide such functionality out-of-the-box. I will try to put up some code together to achieve this.